# Using toHasOne macro with MorpMany relationship

Tags: laravel

I have multiple Model classes that utilize a HasRetirements trait class. Both models use a MorphMany relationship to target the associated retirements table model for each model. Inside the HasRetirements trait class, I also have a isRetired() method as well as a currentRetirement() method. These methods are shown below.

I have come across a macro that can be chained onto an Eloquent relationship so that you can retrieve a single record. The macro toHasOne() utilizes model relationships through a hasMany relationship however my question is could this also be used for a morphMany relationship since it's polymorphic.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-and-using-laravel-eloquent-macros

```
public function currentRetirement()
{
    return $this->retirements()->whereNull('ended_at')->latest()->toHasOne();
}

public function isRetired()
{
    return $this->retirements()->whereNull('ended_at')->exists();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Laravel 5.5, you could register a macro returning a derived class from the `BelongsToMany` relation. This derived class also could be an anonymous class if you are not planning on using it anywhere else. Within the derived class, you need to override the `match` method and return the single object as a relation or `null` otherwise

```
BelongsToMany::macro('asSingleEntity', function() {

        return new class(
            $this->related->newQuery(),
            $this->parent,
            $this->table,        
            $this->foreignPivotKey,
            $this->relatedPivotKey,
            $this->parentKey,
            $this->relatedKey,
            $this->relationName) extends BelongsToMany {

            /**
             * Match the eagerly loaded results to their parents.
             *
             * @param  array   $models
             * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection  $results
             * @param  string  $relation
             * @return array
             */
            public function match(array $models, Collection $results, $relation)
            {
                $dictionary = $this->buildDictionary($results);

                // Once we have an array dictionary of child objects we can easily match the
                // children back to their parent using the dictionary and the keys on the
                // the parent models. Then we will return the hydrated models back out.
                foreach ($models as $model) {
                    if (isset($dictionary[$key = $model->{$this->parentKey}])) {
                        $model->setRelation(
                            // $relation, $this->related->newCollection($dictionary[$key])      // original code
                            $relation, array_first($dictionary[$key])
                        );
                    } else {
                        $model->setRelation($relation, null);
                    }
                }

                return $models;
            }

        };

    });
```

Then, you could simply use it within the model.

```
return $this
        ->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Entity::class, 'pivot_table_name')
        ->asSingleEntity();
```

Comment: Note this doesn't seem to work when using `wherePivot`